# Find Equation of a tangent of a Trig graph given domain of x and angle

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, tangent-line

Usually I am able to find the equation of the tangent when given at least the `x` point... But in case, I just got the domain.

This is my problem of finding the equation of a tangent line of the graph:

$
{-\sin}^2x + {\frac{1}{2}}, x \in [0, {\frac{\pi}{2}}]
$ which
makes an angle of 135◦ with the x−axis. Assume that the scales along the x− axis and
y− axis are the same. Angles are measured anti-clockwise from the positive x−axis.

Which point should I take as the x coordinate... $0$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}$ ?

I would really appreatiate your help, and some explanation, please.

Comment: A nice relationship to know is that $m=\dfrac{y}{x}=\tan\theta$.

Comment: @AndrewChin yes I do know that. But how do I implement it in this scenario ?

Comment: You need to find the derivative to tell you which $x\in[0,\frac\pi2]$ gives you what you need.

Comment: @AndrewChin yes I found it to be `-2sinxcosx`. What do I do now ?

Comment: What is the slope that you need?  Which $x$ value gives you the slope that you need?

Comment: @AndrewChin I need the slope of the tangent line. I know it would equal the derivative `-2sinxcosx` at a specific `x` coordinate... but I have no idea which `x` to use man. Please just give it to me straight

Comment: What does _"makes an angle of 135◦ with the x−axis"_ tell you?

Comment: @AndrewChin so what you are saying is that... `tan135 = -2sinxcosx` ?

Comment: No, but only since you found the derivative incorrectly.  Otherwise you're on the right track.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105850/discussion-between-marvinissacul-and-andrew-chin).

Comment: @ Andrew Chin what is then the correct derivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help has been given in the comments.

$$ y= \frac12 -\sin^2 x $$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= - \sin 2x = \tan 135^{\circ}= -1 $$

$$ 2x= \frac{\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2} ;\,$$

$$ x= \frac{\pi}{4}, \,y=0, $$

$$ x= \frac{5\pi}{4}, \,y=0. $$

among other c0-terminal angles.

The first tangent has equation (slope at given point):

$$ \frac{y}{x-\pi/4} =-1,$$

The second tangent has equation:

$$ \frac{y}{x-5\pi/4} =-1,$$

&c.